# Jupyter Matlab Kernel json error

Tags: linux, matlab, python-3.x, jupyter

I'm honestly not sure what the root of my issue is (whether Jupyter notebooks, MATLAB, matlab_kernel or pymatbridge) so I figured I'd just post the question here with all the tags.

I'm running a MATLAB-kernel Jupyter notebook remotely from a server (Ubuntu 14.04). To set up the MATLAB kernel, I installed pymatbridge and matlab_kernel as per [these](https://anneurai.net/2015/11/12/matlab-based-ipython-notebooks) instructions. It seems like the MATLAB kernel itself is running just fine (tested a few simple MATLAB commands and output and error messages print as expected), and MATLAB itself works fine when I invoke it not in a Jupyter notebook, but when I try to run another MATLAB function in the notebook via

```
addpath('/path/to/function')
y = function(x)
```

I get the following error:

```
[MetaKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 391, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/metakernel/_metakernel.py", line 358, in do_execute
    retval = self.do_execute_direct(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matlab_kernel/kernel.py", line 127, in do_execute_direct
    resp = self._matlab.run_code(code.strip())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matlab_kernel/kernel.py", line 52, in run_code
    return self._engine.run_code(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 319, in run_code
    return self.run_func('evalin', 'base', code, nargout=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 309, in run_func
    nargout=nargout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 272, in _json_response
    return json.loads(self._response(**kwargs), object_hook=decode_pymat)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 331, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 9007 (char 9006)
```

Any ideas what might be causing this error, and what exactly the error means?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is returning `None` because there's an error in your command?  `add path` versus `addpath`?

```
addpath('/path/to/function')
```

Comment: Oh shoot, `add path` was just a typo in my original question; it has been updated. What I'm trying to say is that I can do the exact same call directly in the MATLAB command line via either the MATLAB interface or the MATLAB through the terminal, and both the path adding and function call work fine. It's only through the Jupyter notebook kernel that it throws the error.